# I am using a UILabel and a UITextField and I want to convert all the text in 3 letter groups

Tags: ios, swift, string

I am using a `UILabel` and a `UITextField` in Swift 4 and I want to convert all the text in 3 letter groups.

Example:  "UGCUGGAAUUUAGCAGCCCAU" inputted into the text field needs to return words to the UILabel based on the letters all separated into 3 letter groups.  "UGCUGG" needs to return "x, y". "UGC" would be = to "x" and "UGG" would be equal to "y". How would I do that in Swift 4?

```
@IBOutlet weak var Label: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
@IBAction func decBttn(_ sender: Any) {
    if textField.text == "AAA" || textField.text == "aaa" {
        Label.text = ("Lysine")
    } else if textField.text == "AAG" || textField.text == "aag"{
        Label.text = ("Lysine")
    }else if textField.text == "AAC" || textField.text == "aac"{
        Label.text = ("Asparagine")
    }else if textField.text == "AAU" || textField.text == "aau"{
        Label.text = ("Asparagine")
    }
```

And this goes on for another 200 or so lines.  I need `textField.text` to be a long string, and in this case, "UGCUGGAAUUUAGCAGCCCAU".  I need this string to be sectioned off into groups of three letters and return to `Label.text` with the assigned word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let mapping = ["UGC":"Cysteine", "UGG" : "Tryptophan"]

let text = "UGCUGGAAUUUAGCAGCCCAU"

let characters = text.characters

var index = 0

while index < characters.count {
    let start = text.index(text.startIndex, offsetBy: index)

    var endOffset = index+3
    if index+3 > characters.count {
       endOffset = characters.count
    }

    let end = text.index(text.startIndex, offsetBy: endOffset)
    let range = start..<end

    let groupedSubstring = text[range]
    print(mapping[groupedSubstring] ?? groupedSubstring)
    index = index + 3
}
```

This will give output as below:

Cysteine

Tryptophan

AAU

UUA

GCA

GCC

CAU

Is this your requirement?

Comment: The output is what I am looking for, however, this method will not work for the project.  In the ideal situation, those 3 letter sections will end up translating to certain words. Please review the edited question and that should make things more clear.  I learned that I need to supply some code for context based on what I've been seeing other users do in their questions. Thanks!

Comment: @GrantStinson This answer does what you want. It does translate the letters to words. You would need to populate the `mapping` variable with all of the possible codes and names but this is what you want.

Comment: okay, Thank you.  It may take me some time to populate it.  I was looking for possibly a faster solution but if there isn't one, then this works fine.  Thank you for letting me know!

Comment: would  doing something like `let mapping = [ "UGC" || "ugc" : "Cysteine" , "UGG" || "ugg" : "Tryptophan"]` work for making it work with lowercase letters as well? if so, I can just use find and replace to make this process take less than a minute.

Comment: Don't worry about upper/lowercase in the mapping. Simply change `let groupedSubstring = text[range]` to `let groupedSubstring = text[range].uppercased()`.

Comment: For that to work, would `groupedSubstring` have to be initially lowercased?

Comment: @GrantStinson No. But you need to make sure all of the keys in `mapping` are uppercase.

Comment: When I input the code `print(mapping [groupedSubstring] ?? groupedSubstring)` I get the error "Cannot subscript a value of type '[String : String]' with an index of type 'Substring' "